# InstallUtil.exe Установка и запуск Службы Windows с параметрами

Tags: c#, windows, служба, installutil

Есть Служба: C:\MyService.exe

Произвожу инсталляцию службы:

```
> InstallUtil.exe C:\MyService.exe
```

Но проблема в том, что мне необходимо запускать службу с параметрами (например C:\MyService.exe -param1 -param2), средствами **InstallUtil.exe** я не нашел как этого сделать, только если править в ручную в реестре (но это не вариант).

Подскажите, как еще можно произвести инсталляцию службы для её запуска с параметрами.

---

Пользовательские установки в коде Службы выглядят следующим образом:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class MyServiceInstaller : Installer
{
    public MyServiceInstaller()
    {
        var processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

        serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "MyService";
        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "MyService";
        serviceInstaller.Description = "My Service";

        processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual;

        this.Installers.Add(processInstaller);
        this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вроде решил проблему подпиской на событие:

```
base.BeforeInstall += new InstallEventHandler(MyServiceInstaller_BeforeInstall);

void MyServiceInstaller_BeforeInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        base.Context.Parameters["assemblyPath"] =
        string.Format("\"{0}\" -param1", base.Context.Parameters["assemblyPath"]);
    }
```

Теперь к запуску службы добавится **"C:/MyService.exe" -param1**

**Если у кого будут замечания или более пряморукие варианты, с радостью пишите!**